# How to change row background color in SlickGrid

Tags: slickgrid

I started a new project in slickgrid.

[I am working this sample.](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/examples/example3-editing.html)

How can I change the background color of the row I want ?
For example : first row backcolor to red , second row backcolor to blue ...
Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's better to post your code in the question instead of giving us a link.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want your first row red, your second row blue etc then define it in css using the `nth-of-type` selector and the `.slick-row` class selector:

```
/*Colour the first row red*/
.slick-row:nth-of-type(1){
background: #FF0000;
}

/*Colour the second row blue*/
.slick-row:nth-of-type(2){
background: #0000FF;
}
```